# deploying a asp.net website having managed c++/cli dll reference that is using OpenCV libraries

Tags: asp.net, iis, opencv, c++-cli

i have created a asp.net web application. It contains a C++/cli DLL reference which is using OpenCV libraries

the web application works fine while deploying in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 but as soon as i try to deploy it in IIS 7.5, the execution stops and Visual Studio just-in-time Debugging appears asking for possible debugger having a list containing the same c++/cli dll project name.

then i select the DLL project and click yes in visual studio just-in-time debugger, the C++/CLI DLL project opens and a attach security warning appears giving a message

Attaching to this process can potentially harm your computer. If the information below looks suspicious or you are unsure,do not attach to this process.

as i press Attach Button. the Breakpoint appears at the starting brace of the called function of the C++/CLI DLL, giving a System.StackOverflowException.

this function contains the use OpenCV library functions and classes.

Although its working fine in microsoft visual studio 2010 which also uses IIS web server, then why its not working when i deploy the same project in IIS directly without using Visual Studio.

Also when i tried to deploy this asp.net project in a computer having no Visual Studio but Dotnet Framework 4.0 and MS VC++ redistribution 10 installed, in IIS 7.5, it throws an exception "cannot open the DLL or its dependencies"

i want to  Deploy my web Application in IIS 7.5.....can anyone help me to resolve the problem  i am facing in IIS 7.5